# How to filter list of tuple rdd

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have a list of tuple that I'd like to filter were the number is **greater than 10** and then **show the count** of the filtered rdd

rdd_ = [('Mike', 10), ('Adam', 9), ('Peter', 15), ('Vicky', 26), ('Tim', 45)]

result_rdd = [('Peter', 15), ('Vicky', 26), ('Tim', 45)]

count_rdd = [3]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter` and `count` methods of RDD:

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([('Mike', 10), ('Adam', 9), ('Peter', 15), ('Vicky', 26), ('Tim', 45)])

result_rdd = rdd.filter(lambda x: x[1] > 10)

count_rdd = result_rdd.count()
```